# Stream CMD output to Select-String

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Is there a way to fluidly stream CMD standard output to PowerShell to `Select-String`?

I have tried every method I can find, but every way I find stores the info in a variable before piping it to be worked with. It has to be a stream because the standard out can be well over 20GBs in size and ends up causing an out of memory exception before the process crashes.

Here is the command I have been using:

```
gunzip.exe -c "*_2015-06-05_*" |powershell.exe "& {$input | select-string -pattern '1292681581' | Out-File C:\Users\xadministrator\desktop\test2.txt -append}"
```

Comment: What happens when you pipe it directly to Select-String? `gunzip.exe -c "_2015-06-05_*" | Select-String -Pattern '1292681581' | Out-File: ...` EDIT: Ooooh you're running this from CMD itself. Right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
powershell.exe "& {gunzip.exe -c '*_2015-06-05_*' | select-string ...}"
```

You should also be able to do this entirely in CMD (using [`find`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490906.aspx) or [`findstr`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) for the filtering) if you find PowerShell too slow:

```
gunzip.exe -c "*_2015-06-05_*" | find "1292681581" >> "C:\Users\xadministrator\desktop\test2.txt"
```

However, processing 20 GB of data is going to take some time either way.

Comment: *facepalm*, i cannot believe I didn't try this already, only issue is its incredibly slow.

Comment: Unfortunately I am trying to get rid of a scripts winGrep reliance in a Powershell script so I can add multi-tasking functionality so doing this in powershell in a must.