# Execute CMD command and Stream CMD results to StreamWriter

Tags: powershell, streamwriter, powershell-1.0

I am trying to execute a CMD command and stream the results of the commands to stream writer. The reason for this is the log files I am trying to sift through are up to a 1gb each and storing the results into a variable can easily use up several gigs of memory. I also would like to pipe out to StreamWriter because of the beautiful performance.

Here is the excerpt from my script.

```
$StreamWriter = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "test.txt"
$SearchString = "2016_06_*"
$SearchLogs = "2016_*.log"

"CMD /C gunzip.exe -c $SearchLogs |grep -i `"$SearchString`"" | $StreamWriter.WriteLine($_)

$StreamWriter.Flush()
$StreamWriter.Close()
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not mix CMD and PowerShell. Use one or the other. I already told you that the [last time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35767787/1630171).
2. Do not use PowerShell v1 anymore. Any still supported Windows system can run at least PowerShell v2. Upgrade now.
3. You don't need CMD for running executables from PowerShell. I had told you that as well.
4. If you put a commandline in quotes PowerShell will simply echo it, not execute it.
5. For filtering wildcard matches use the `-like` operator.
6. Stream writers don't read from the pipeline. You need to wrap them in a `ForEach-Object` statement.

```bsh
$StreamWriter = [IO.StreamWriter]'test.txt'
$SearchString = "2016_06_*"
$SearchLogs   = "2016_*.log"

gunzip.exe -c $SearchLogs |
  Where-Object { $_ -like $SearchString } |
  ForEach-Object { $StreamWriter.WriteLine($_) }

$StreamWriter.Flush()
$StreamWriter.Close()
```